# Saving the bounding rectangle of a circle OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, mobile, crop

Hi i am using HoughCircle to detect circles i have also made a bounding box to display around the outline of the circle what i want to do now is to grab the image inside the bounding boxes and save them to a file or a bitmap.

Here is my code

```
            // accumulator value
            double dp = 1;
            // minimum distance between the center coordinates of detected circles in pixels
            double minDist = gray_src.rows() / 8;
            // min and max radiuis
            int minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 500;
            //Last two
            double iCanny = 100, accum = 25;

            // create a Mat object to store the circles detected
            Mat circles = new Mat();

            // find the circle in the image
            Imgproc.HoughCircles(outlineThick, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDist, iCanny, accum, minRadius, maxRadius);

            // get the number of circles detected
            int numberOfCircles = (circles.rows() == 0) ? 0 : circles.

            // int x = (int) circleCoordinates[0], y = (int) circleCoordinates[1];
            Point pt;


            Rect[] roiArray = new Rect[numberOfCircles];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {
                double circleCoordinates[] = circles.get(0, i);
                pt = new Point(Math.round(circleCoordinates[0]), Math.round(circleCoordinates[1]));
                //circle's outline
                int radius = (int) Math.round(circleCoordinates[2]);
                Log.d("LOG", "Circle: X=" + Double.toString(circleCoordinates[0]) + " Y=" + Double.toString(circleCoordinates[1]));
                Imgproc.circle(src, pt, radius, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
                Imgproc.rectangle(src, new Point(pt.x - (radius + 1), pt.y - (radius + 1)), new Point(pt.x + (radius + 1), pt.y + (radius + 1)), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
                Rect roi = new Rect(new Point(pt.x - (radius + 1), pt.y - (radius + 1)), new Point(pt.x + (radius + 1), pt.y + (radius + 1)));
                roiArray[i] = roi;
            }
```

I have tried using things like:`submat(dst,mask);` but all i get when i save the image is the full size image and not a cropped version

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Submat accepts also a Rect. Use that!

Comment: thanks Miki, using submat worked for me